# Taurus fails my test if at least 1 error happens

Tags: jmeter, taurus

If at least one error is returned from the server during the test execution, the final status of the test is set to 'fail'. I am sending quite a lot of requests during the test execution and a small percentage of errors is expected. Is there any way to prevent them from failing the whole test?

[Screenshot of the fail status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xay1s.png)

I tried to set custom Pass/Fail criteria on the scenario level but it did not help:

```
criteria:
    - fail of my-label>3% for 30s, stop as failed
```

It feels like some default Pass/Fail criteria are defined and I can not override them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see where does Taurus sets the status of the test to "fail"

[image]

Even if there is 50% of failures and there are no [Pass/Fail criteria](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) set Taurus returns zero [exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) which means "success"

If you want to set a specific request status to `OK` no matter whether it failed or not in reality it can be done using [JSR223 Block](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JSR223-Blocks)

```
jsr223:
  execute: after
  script-text: prev.setSuccessful(true)
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Dmitri, thank you for so quick reply. Sorry, I have a really small reputation on Stack Overflow, and it does not let me add screenshots to the questions. Instead, I added a link to the screenshot. Please, click on the "Screenshot of the fail status" link in my question. On the screenshot, you may see that I have a 99.44% success rate for my endpoint but the status in the table is set to FAIL. By the way, the exit status is zero (success) as you have mentioned. I just want to avoid FAIL status in the report. Is there any way to influence this behavior?

Comment: The way of "influence this behaviuor" has been provided. Taurus considers transaction as FAILed even in case one of million requests fails.

Comment: I was asking about influencing this default behaviour "FAIL status even in case one of a million requests fails". Is there any way not to fail a transaction if there is a single error?